# Pass variable between functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following line of code that is executed inside the `$(document).ready`:

```
$('#sliding_menu_area').toggle(effect, reAlign);
```

`reAlign` is a function that is declared outside of the `$(document).ready` main function in my `.js` file.

I have a variable called `tag` that is declared also inside the `$(document).ready` and I need to pass the variable to the `reAlign` function. I tried

```
$('#sliding_menu_area').toggle(effect, reAlign(tag));
```

but it didn't work. Can I declare the `tag` variable as a global so functions declared outside of `$(document).ready` to be able to access it? So far the functions declared inside the `$(document).ready` can access it just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you answered your question. Just put your tag as global and you should be ok

Comment: @FrenchiInLA No, please don't solve problems by creating globals

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#sliding_menu_area').toggle(effect, reAlign(tag));
```

your code executes `reAlign` with the `tag` argument, and then passes the return value to `toggle` (as the second argument).

```
$('#sliding_menu_area').toggle(effect, function() { reAlign(tag); });
```

Answer (score 2):

I would generally avoid making anything global...or at least conserve your global namespace as much as possible.  For instance, I have a Page class, which I use for various functions, such as Page.notify("some message").  When I need to make something accessible to the entire page, I create a variable like Page.Tag.  If you only need tag for the reAlign method, then go with Karoly's suggestion and avoid making something global that doesn't truly need to be global.

Comment: It's not a global variable, OP wants to pass it to a function.

Comment: He asked, quote: "Can I declare the tag variable as a global so functions declared outside of $(document).ready to be able to access it?"  I was answering that question saying to avoid globals if he can.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice the OP had suggested a global. Take my downvote back

Answer (score 1):

Karoly's answer works, another alternative is to do the following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

```
$('#sliding_menu_area').toggle(effect, reAlign.bind(window, tag));
```

That binds your function so that when it's called, it's called with `window` as the `this` variable and tag as the first argument to the function. Basically the same thing that Karoly suggested, with a different idiom.

Answer (score 0):

If the `reAlign` function needs to know the DOM element (which is passed as `this`), it would be better to use:

```
$('#sliding_menu_area').toggle(effect, function () {
  reAlign.call(this, tag);
});
```

Comment: `reAlign` is a global function, bad practice to expect `this` to be anything other than `window`